# change backend html wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, clickable

I have a WordPress site with a custom theme: 
http://prezorgnl.server157.nognietactief.nl/

And there is a clickable button I want to copy and replace with another clickable button. In the section "Zorg Diensten" there is a clickable button called "Klik Hier" which I want to copy and replace it with the basketball icon in the section "Wat bieden wij?"

How do I change this with CSS/HTML

CSS code:

```css
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.angle-effect.custom-btn::after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: skew(50deg) scale(1.1, 1);
    width: 0;
}
.custom-btn::after, .angle-effect.custom-btn::after, .btn {
    transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
}
.blog #main-menu.navbar-default, .archive #main-menu.navbar-default, .single #main-menu.navbar-default, .page-template-default #main-menu.navbar-default, .publish-date, .custom-btn::after, .hex, .hex::before, .hex::after, .content-icon-hex, .hex.scroll-top::after, .hex.scroll-top::before, .hex.scroll-top, .section-title::after, .carousel-indicators li.active, .pricing-item:hover .item-head, .pricing-item .item-name::after, .slide-nav:hover, .gallery-item figure:hover .item-description, .news-article .meta-icon, .parallax-title::after, .causes-post .custom-progress-bar, .single-causes-post .custom-progress-bar, .donate-btn:hover, .team-member-box:hover .member-designation::after, .owl-page.active, .team-member-box::before, .service-box:hover .service-icon-hex, .service-box:hover .service-icon-hex::before, .service-box:hover .service-icon-hex::after, .event-timeline, .blog-sidebar .btn:hover, .link-hex:hover {
    background-color: #003996;
}
.custom-btn::after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f39c12;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.custom-btn::after, .angle-effect.custom-btn::after, .btn {
    transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
}
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hex, .hex::before, .hex::after, .carousel-indicators li.active, .white-bg .custom-btn, .gray-bg .custom-btn, .custom-btn:hover, .post-box .custom-btn, .galleryFilter .current, .time-circle .time-number, .contact-form-container .custom-btn, .contact-info .contact-address li::before, .comment-form .form-control:focus, .contact-form-container .form-control:focus, .contact-form-container .custom-btn:hover, .owl-page.active, .single-event-post .time-circle .time-number, .link-hex {
    border-color: #003996;
}
.white-bg .custom-btn, .gray-bg .custom-btn {
    border-color: #f39c12;
    color: #0d0d0d;
}
.custom-btn {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.custom-btn {
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
.custom-btn::after, .angle-effect.custom-btn::after, .btn {
    transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
}
```

And this is the CSS I want to replace it with:

```css
.fa-dribbble::before {
    content: "";
}
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-feature-settings: normal;
    font-kerning: auto;
    font-language-override: normal;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-synthesis: weight style;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-rendering: auto;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.social-buttons a {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
.social-buttons a {
    color: #0d0d0d;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 22px;
}
a {
    color: #0d0d0d;
}
a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: #428bca;
}
.team-member-box {
    color: #737373;
    text-align: center;
}
html, body {
    color: #737373;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
html, body {
    color: #737373;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to post more info. It depends if that button was created in the theme or generated dynamically with WordPress. Where's this button? What does it do?

Comment: Hi Dustin, thanks for your response, the button was created in theme, By clicking the buttons it opens a new page with new content on it. I placed the CSS of both buttons in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace all: [image: replace]

with this? [image: with this?]

Comment: Hi Luci, I can't add no images since I don;t have enough Reputation. Otherwise I could show you. But to answer your question , The "Klik hier" button you have placed I want to replace in the section above with a basketball icon

Comment: Hi Luci, I was wondering if you still can help me with this if that's possible? Thank you in andvanced